# How to display the icon check from the application list in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6zvbjl-tpvkg3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

***HTML***

```
<nz-dropdown class="filter-dropdown" [nzTrigger]="'click'" nzPlacement="bottomRight">
      <a nz-dropdown nz-tooltip>
        {{ activeFilter.filterBy }} <i nz-icon [type]="activeFilter.order === 'ASC' ? 'up' : 'down'"></i>
      </a>
      <ul nz-menu>
        <li nz-submenu nzTitle="Application">
          <ul *ngFor="let apps of appList">
            <li nz-menu-item>
            {{apps.name}}
            <i nz-icon nzType="check" *ngIf="activeFilter.appName=='apps.name'" nzTheme="outline"></i>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nz-dropdown>
```

***TS***

```
listOfPosition: NzPlacementType[] = ['bottomLeft', 'bottomCenter', 'bottomRight', 'topLeft', 'topCenter', 'topRight'];

  activeFilter = {
    filterBy: 'Application',
    appName: '',
    length: 100,
    status: 'ALL',
    order: 'ASC',
    grouped: false
  };

  appList = [{
    name: 'App1'
  },{
    name: 'App2'
  },{
    name: 'App3'
  },{
    name: 'App4'
  },{
    name: 'App5'
  },{
    name: 'App6'
  },{
    name: 'App7'
  },{
    name: 'App8'
  },{
    name: 'App9'
  },{
    name: 'App10'
  }]


  ngOnInit() {

  }
  statuName(param){
    if(param=="ALL"){return "All"}
     if(param=="ACK"){return "Acknowledged"}
      if(param=="READ"){return "Read"}
       if(param=="NEW"){return "New"}
  }
  handleFilter(targetFilter?: string, value?: any) {
    this.activeFilter[targetFilter] = value;
    console.log(targetFilter);
    console.log(this.activeFilter);

    console.log(this.activeFilter);
    if (targetFilter === 'order') {
      // ?direction = 'asc' || 'desc']
    }
  }
```

What I'm trying to do here is when I select from the application it the icon should be display which is the `<i nz-icon nzType="check"></i>`. for example I choose the `App1` then it should display the icon check from the App1, but if I choose the App2 then it will display the check on the App2 because the active is the App2.

[image]

Comment: you can record the selected item

Comment: @Azad can you make a sample on stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recored the selected index in your componet class, when click on a item pass the selected item into `handleFilter()` method as well.

here is code segments, merge it with your application it should work.

```
  template: `
    <nz-dropdown
      class="filter-dropdown"
      [nzTrigger]="'click'"
      nzPlacement="bottomRight"
    >
      <a nz-dropdown nz-tooltip>
        {{ activeFilter.filterBy }}
        <i nz-icon [type]="activeFilter.order === 'ASC' ? 'up' : 'down'"></i>
      </a>
      <ul nz-menu>
        <li nz-submenu nzTitle="Application">
          <ul *ngFor="let apps of appList; let i = index">
            <li nz-menu-item (click)="handleFilter('appName', apps.code, i)">
              {{ apps.name }}
              <i
                nz-icon
                nzType="check"
                *ngIf="i == selectedAppIdx"
                nzTheme="outline"
              ></i>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nz-dropdown>
  `,
```

in componet class define `selectedAppIdx` variable

```
selectedAppIdx = -1;

handleFilter(targetFilter?: string, value?: any, idx?: any) {
   this.activeFilter[targetFilter] = value;
   this.selectedAppIdx = idx;
   console.log(targetFilter);
   console.log(this.activeFilter);

   console.log(this.activeFilter);
   if (targetFilter === "order") {
       // ?direction = 'asc' || 'desc']
   }
}
```